# A palavra "status" faz parte do Português?

Tags: gramática, vocabulário, neologismos

Noto o uso da palavra *"status"*, que no inglês tem o sentido de *"estado atual de algo"*, com o mesmo objetivo, posso dizer que a palavra *"status"* faz parte do português?

Answer (score 16):

"Status" é a palavra latina que se transformou, por meio de vários processos linguísticos, na palavra portuguesa "estado". No entanto, a palavra original do latim foi reintroduzida no português, além de passar a fazer parte de outras línguas não-românicas, como o inglês. O mesmo ocorreu a centenas de outras palavras latinas, em virtude, principalmente, da popularização de termos científicos.

Portanto, faz parte sim, da língua portuguesa, já que é usada de modo corriqueiro pela maioria dos falantes.

Comment: Entretanto, ela não consta no VOLP (Vocabulário Ortográfico da Língua Portuguesa) (pode-se consultar no site: http://www.academia.org.br/abl/cgi/cgilua.exe/sys/start.htm?sid=23). Talvez seja um neologismo?

Comment: Sim, mas é a língua que determina o que vai ser registrado no dicionário (com algum tempo de atraso), e não o oposto.

Comment: Você tem toda a razão no seu comentário. Mas isso quer dizer que até o momento a palavra faz parte da *língua falada*. Dizer que ela "faz parte do português" talvez não seja totalmente correto. De todas as formas, eu só estava querendo ajudar a complementar a sua resposta. :)

Comment: @LuizVieira Por essa lógica, nenhuma palavra faz parte dos idiomas sem tradição escrita.

Comment: @apagueestaconta Não é essa a questão. Uma palavra pode não fazer parte da ortografia oficialmente aceita e ser amplamente utilizada e compreendida na lingua falada. Tanto que, como o Otavio bem colocou, eventualmente ela pode ser aceita devido ao seu amplo uso. A questão é diferenciar os casos para permitir que alguém entenda o porquê de eventualmente não se achar no dicionário uma palavra comumente utilizada. Agora, apenas por curiosidade, que idioma(s) não tem tradição escrita?

Answer (score 8):

Sim, *status* faz parte do português por [empréstimo](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empr%C3%A9stimo_(lingu%C3%ADstica)). Originalmente um [latinismo](http://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno/portugues/definicao/latinismo%20_990216.html), vem sofrendo reintrodução via [anglicismo](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anglicismo) - que por sua vez também sofreu latinismo.

Como um ponto interessante, status possui plural em inglês, [*statuses*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/status). Em português, entretanto, não - por ser [4ª declinação latina de –ūs](http://gramaticalatimclassico.blogspot.com/2006/07/iii-flexo-dos-substantivos.html), não possui forma plural diferenciada.

Answer (score 0):

A palavra "status" é indubitavelmente de origem latina. Estranhamente, aparece com frequência com a grafia de "statu", como na expressão "statu quo". Sendo a palavra e a expressão ambas latinas, a versão "statu quo" deve ser considerada uma forma errónea da versão latina "status quo". Para se fazer o aportuguesamento correcto, a versão portuguesa não poderia começar com as letras "st" ou terminar em "tu", para já nem falar da segunda palavra da expressão ("quo"). De facto, há séculos que a palavra latina "status" evoluiu para a nossa palavra "estado" e como tal é pacificamente usada e aceite. Resumindo: Se quisermos utilizar a versão latina, diremos "status quo"; se optarmos pela versão portuguesa, usaremos as palavras "estado actual".

Comment: Boas-vindas ao Portuguese SE! Obrigado pela contribuição, mas sugerir que "status" seria somente latim e não português não parece correto (confira as respostas mais antigas). Uma palavra não precisa ser aportuguesada para pertencer ao português. A palavra "status" é de uso difundido, escrita usualmente sem itálico e se encontra em diversos dicionários (e.g., [Priberam](https://dicionario.priberam.org/status) e [Aulete](https://www.aulete.com.br/status)).

Comment: Jose Lopes, bem-vindo ao Portuguese StackExchange! Agradeço também pela tua contribuição. Porém, há alguns problemas graves na tua resposta: a) A forma preferencial é *statu quo*, segundo o [Priberam](https://www.flip.pt/Duvidas-Linguisticas/Duvida-Linguistica/DID/1116), b) A versão aportuguesada, que só faria sentido se os falantes a vissem como português e não latina, poderia ter *st-*, mas provavelmente não teria por como o português funciona c) a expressão *statu quo* não se refere ao estado atual, refere-se ao estado anterior ou original. Ainda assim, muito obrigado pela contribuição!